# Why does SOH CAH TOA hold?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, definition, proof-explanation

Even looking on the Wiki pages I have a hard time figuring this one out.

But why does SOH CAH TOA hold? As in, why is $\sin(x)$ the same as the opposite over hypotenuse of a right triangle? Why is $\cos(x)$ the adjacent over hypotenuse? Why is $\tan(x)$ the opposite over the adjacent? And why don't any of these work for right angles as the reference theta?

I understand that these facts are easily used but if I were trying to invent this for the first time I'd be totally lost. I don't understand where these trig functions come from, what their format definitions are, why they're defined this way, where they come from, why they're true, how we know they're true, etc. To me they are mysterious functions that everyone just uses and takes for granted but I have no idea how they work.

Comment: These are definitions of sine, cosine, and tangent. This is a way of remembering definitions, not a way of remembering theorems.

Comment: So $\sin(x)$ is literally _defined_ as opposite-over-hypotenuse of a non-right angle of a non-degenerate right triangle?

Comment: @user525966 If we don't wish over-formalize, yes - for $x\in (0,\frac\pi2)$.

Comment: That's the usual intro definition, yes. Even degenerate right triangles, when the angle is a multiple of $90$ degrees (including $0$.)

Comment: Is the "intro definition" the actual definition or an oversimplified one from a much more general definition? What's the non-intro definition?

Comment: @user525966 That's a matter of taste. Some would use "the one and only twice-differentiable function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $f''=-f$, $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$". But it's rather an approach which we came up with afterwards for the sake of formal foundation.

Comment: The non-intro definition could be in terms of a power series (see Taylor polynomials) or a functional equation (see differential equations).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli But then, that definition doesn't fit into the tag, "algebra-precalculus"

Comment: The "intro definition" is correct so far as it goes, but it only handles angles up to 90 degrees.  Eventually one want to extend the definition to other angles, then to all real numbers, then even to complex numbers.  This doesn't make the original definition wrong, but more advanced definitions are better for more advanced purposes.  Historically, the definition you've been taught came first, by many centuries.

Comment: There are a lot of advanced definitions, from "the real part of $e^{ix}$" to similarly. But all require calculus or some such.

Comment: One of the semi-advanced definitions that I prefer, and which is more tightly related to the triangle definition, is that $\sin(\theta)$, for $\theta > 0$, is equal to "the $y$-coordinate at the end of a path that travels counterclockwise around the unit circle in the Cartesian coordinate plane for a total length of $\theta$". But even that requires some analytical thinking in order to define lengths of paths along the circle.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I meant that the choice of a non-intro definition is a matter of taste, because they are all more or less dependent on some principles related to analysis to acheive a fully formal standing.

Comment: The first definition I learned, all those years ago, is that $(\cos t, \sin t)$ correspond to the $(x,y)$ coordinates of a point on the unit circle that is a distance $t$ from the point $(1,0)$ traveled along the arc in a counterclockwise direction.  But, I will concede that "SOH-CAH-TOA" is a definition.  Although, one that breaks down for angles not in $0<\theta<90$

Comment: @DougM Do you think the unit circle is a more robust definition to use?

Comment: It is how I still tend to think about them.  But it is a little bit more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If two right triangles share an angle $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$, then they are similar. In particular the ratio of corresponding side lengths are equal. So 
the quantities
$$
\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypoteneuse}};\quad \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypoteneuse}}
$$
are the same for every right triangle with angle $\theta$. Hence these quantities are functions of $\theta$ and we may define
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypoteneuse}};\quad \sin\theta=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypoteneuse}}
$$

Comment: And, if you have the usual picture in mind with the adjacent along the $x$-axis: $\cos\theta$ is the **c**entral displacement and $\sin\theta$ is the **s**ideways displacement.